# Quotient from integers in C

Tags: c, division, integer-division

I want to get the result of a division of two integers. For example the integers 6 and 25. If I divide the integers I get `6/25 = 0` as the answer. I want the result to be `6/25 = 0.24`. How can I do it?

Comment: What format do you want the result in?

Comment: Don't use __float__, instead use __double__ which is the same as float, but can hold larger and more precise values. Space needed is not a concern on modern computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%.2f\n",(float)6/25);
}
```

Comment: The `./` "operator" as in `6./25` also would do the job. :-) No casting necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the values to floating point first. For example

```
result = (double)a / (double)b.
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast any of them to a float

```
float result = a/(float)b;
```

Comment: Thank you , this one worked ! :D

Comment: If this answers your question you should mark it as accepted answer, so if anyone comes with the same problem, can find easily the solution

Comment: I suggest preferring `double` over `float`.  If you're dividing a larg integer by a small one (such as 1), there's a good chance a `float` will give an inexact result.

Comment: @TomKarzes there's a good chance for that no matter what

Comment: @harold if your doubles are 64-bit and your ints are 32-bit, then a double can hold any int exactly.  And that's a very common situation (the computer I'm using right now is like that).  But even if you're using a computer with 64-bit ints, you're still going to have fewer problems with `double`.  I have never found a need to use `float`.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, but that rarely saves you from a division (sometimes yes), for example take the very example the OP used: 6/25. Can't represent that with a float. Still can't represent that with a double, or indeed any size of binary floating point number.

Comment: @harold Right, I was just walking about the case where the result is an exact integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the numerator by `1.0` if you want to avoid casting.

```
printf("%f\n", a * 1.0 / b);
```